# Problem with matching multiple perspectives using fspy

Tags: add-on, camera, fspy

So I've been using fspy for a few days now and I took a few pictures of a house in my neighborhood and tried to model it inside blender and ran into some problem during modeling.After some camera matching in fspy I tried to do a blockout of my scene using some cube.[image]
The first picture matches just fine, then I add the second camera,and I set my 3D curser to the first Camera and scale the whole model using 3D curser as the pivot point until the model sort of match the second perspective.[image]
Now the problem is already starting to appear.The front side of the building is matching just fine, but the back side is actually stretching out.
I did my best tring to model it using the first two picture, but the problem is even more noticeable when the third picture came in.
[image]
The back side of the building is too far off that I can't even continue doing my modeling. What is going on here? Is there something I was doing wrong in the modeling process? Here is what I did in fspy.
[image]
I basically just set the origin points of the three pictures to the top right conner of the building. Here are the original pictures.
I apperciate all the help I can get. Thanks!!!(Sorry if I'm being a bit incoherent in my description. English isn't my native language.)
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: fSpy helps but it's not always easy to find the exact X, Y or Z axis, when the lines are not long enough in the picture and even worse when the lines are not really straight or parallel or perpendicular, in that case you need to cheat a bit, build your building as close as possible to what it looks, then, when you're about glad, project the image on the faces

Comment: So there's really no easy way to fix it then, I tried to match the fov of all the scenes as close as possible but the model still ended up looking fine from one angle and far off from another